# Diferencia al agregar método

Tags: javascript

*Cual es la diferencia entre crear un **método de un objeto con el prototipo y sin él**?, tengo entendido que al crearlo con el `prototipo`, sus instancias heredan sus métodos y propiedades, **entonces por eso sí puedo usar la función limpiar y la agregar no**.
Entonces **para que me serviría** una función que no estuviese en el prototipo del constructor?*

```js
function Metodologia(){
  this.metodo = "Paso número 1";
}

Metodologia.prototype.limpiar = function()
{ this.metodo = "Paso número 2" };

Metodologia.agregar = function()
{ this.metodo = "Paso número PI" };

var i = new Metodologia();

console.log(i.metodo); 
i.limpiar();
console.log(i.metodo);
// i.agregar(); <- Causará error
```

Comment: Tu método `agregar` es estático mientras que los demás son de instancia, los usos son variados y es algo muy básico en la programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: @Gerardo javascript no es orientado objetos, todo intento de hablar orientado a objetos no es sino el resultado de simular dicho funcionamiento con conceptos distintos. En éste caso `agregar` es una propiedad de la función `Metodologia` no afecta en nada al objeto referenciado en `this` mucho menos al prototipo, sólo es accesible a él a través de `Metodologia.agregar.call(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces con el metodo agregar esta relacionado a una practica llamada [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) o [cache de metodos](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/).

Cuando utilizas el operador `new` la instancia que es retornada solo tiene acceso a los objetos definido en el mismo con `this` y a la cadena del prototipo `prototype`.

Ahora bien cuando haces:

```
Metodologia.agregar = function() { 
  this.metodo = "Paso número PI"
};
```

No estas definiendo el metodo `agregar()` ni al objeto en si y ni al `prototype` sino que lo estas agregando(attaching) a la definicion del objeto `Metodologia`.

Para poder acceder al metodo agregar, tendras que utilizar la notacion de puntos y enviarle la referencia del objeto `Metodologia` para que pueda acceder a las propiedades del objeto:

```js
function Metodologia(){
  this.metodo = "Paso número 1";
}

Metodologia.prototype.limpiar = function()
{ this.metodo = "Paso número 2" };

Metodologia.agregar = function(metodologia){ 
 console.log(metodologia.metodo);
};

var i = new Metodologia();

console.log(i.metodo); 
i.limpiar();
console.log(i.metodo);
Metodologia.agregar(i);
```

Digamos que el metodo agregar es "equivalente" al static de los lenguajes orientados a objetos: no estan presentes en el objeto, pero si en la definicion de la clase.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Einer